# Get pieStartValue from Google Charts API

Tags: google-visualization

I'm using Google Charts API to create an interactive pie chart that responds on mouse clicks.  By clicking any segment, it should increase it by 5% and reduce the segment to the left by 5%.  This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

          // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
          google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

          // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
          google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

          // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
          // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
          // draws it.
          function drawChart() {

            // Create the data table.
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', 'Index');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Emphasis');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Position');
            data.addRows([
              ['Option A',  20,   1],
              ['Option B',  30,   2],
              ['Option C',  50,   3]
            ]);

            // Set chart options
            var options = {
              height: 300,
              pieStartAngle: 0,
              slices: {
                0: {color: 'blue'},
                1: {color: 'green'},
                2: {color: 'yellow'}
              },
              enableInteractivity: false,
            };

            // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

            function selectHandler() {
              var selectedItem = chart.getSelection()[0];
              var numRows = data.getNumberOfRows();
              // verify the selection isn't inexplicibly invalid
              if (selectedItem && selectedItem.row < numRows && selectedItem.row >= 0) {
                // find the two items we're looking at
                var curItem = selectedItem.row;

                // we either want selected.row + 1 or we want 0 if the selected item was the last one

                var otherItem = selectedItem.row == numRows - 1 ? 0 : selectedItem.row + 1;
                var otherItemValue = data.getValue(otherItem , 1);
                if (otherItemValue == 0) {
                  var numRowsNew = data.getNumberOfRows();
                  var otherItem = numRows - (curItem + otherItem);
                }

                if (otherItem==0) {
                    var options = {
                      height: 300,
                      pieStartAngle: 18,
                      slices: {
                        0: {color: 'blue'},
                        1: {color: 'green'},
                        2: {color: 'yellow'}
                      },
                      enableInteractivity: false,
                    };
                } else {
                   var options = {
                      height: 300,
                      pieStartAngle: 0,
                      slices: {
                        0: {color: 'blue'},
                        1: {color: 'green'},
                        2: {color: 'yellow'}
                      },
                      enableInteractivity: false,
                    };
                }

                // calculate the new values
                var activePerc  = data.getValue(curItem , 1);
                var activePercNew = parseInt(activePerc)+5;
                var adjacePerc    = data.getValue(otherItem , 1);
                var adjacePercNew = parseInt(adjacePerc  )-5;

                if (activePerc == 100) {

                } else {

                // update the chart
                data.setValue(curItem,1, activePercNew);
                data.setValue(otherItem,1, adjacePercNew);

                chart.draw(data, options);
                // the thing we just clicked on was redrawn so it lost its handler, reinstate it:
                google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectHandler);
                }
              }
            }

            function resize () {
              var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
              chart.draw(data, options);
            }

            window.onload = resize();
            window.onresize = resize;

            google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectHandler);
            chart.draw(data, options);
          }

        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="chart_div"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I know that is not perfect yet.  But if you click once on option A (blue) it works fine. If you click once on Option B (green) it works fine.  If you click **once** on Option C (yellow) it also works fine.  But if you click a second time on Option C (yellow), the rotation is wrong.  The first click initiated a pieStartAngle of 18 degrees (5%).

So my question: How can I obtain the current pieStartAngle between mouse clicks?  If the angle has changed, I would like the new click on Option C to rotate the chart by another 18 degrees.  And so on.  I there for need the new angle to add 18 degrees to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The options variable is a simple JS object, so you can just use options.pieStartAngle to access it - both for getting and setting.

So to get the value between clicks (either before or after redrawing) you can use:

```
var pieAngle = options.pieStartAngle;
```

Or to set it to 0 (or any other value) between clicks you can do this before you redraw:

```
options.pieStartAngle = 0;
```

Here's a quick fiddle that keeps the start angle at 0: http://jsfiddle.net/6kcom3fj/

Updated: To increment the angle by 18 for each click, you just need a variable outside your function that keeps track of the current angle, and then increment that by 18 on each click and set the options.pieStartAngle to that. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6kcom3fj/2/ - I marked relevant sections with UPDATE: comments :)

Update again: Occurred to me you might only want to push the angle round when you change the last section. Here's a version which does that: http://jsfiddle.net/6kcom3fj/4/

Comment: HeatherEMSL - Thanks for your help again.  I updated my question to be more precise.  I would like to rotate the chart continiously in the same direction if I click on Option C.  Thus, original startAngle (0) + 18 degrees, then a new click will rotate the startangle to 18+18 degrees.  I tried the var pieAngle option you gave me, but then lose all functionallity on the chart.

Comment: Ah in that case you just need to do options.pieStartAngle += 18; before each redraw. Updating my answer...